# UWP+Prism MVVM - How do I set the value of a view model property via XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, prism

I have a property in a view model which I would like to be able to set via the XAML but I can't figure out how to do it.
I have a pretty basic user control (containing a list of items), two of which are to be placed on a page and I would like to be able to set one to be a 'Source' (defined by an enum) and one to be a 'Target'.

[The code below has been stripped down quite a bit so apologies if I've accidentally made some mistakes or missed something out.]

My enumeration is:

```
public enum ConversionSide
{
    Source, // Convert something FROM whatever is here.
    Target  // Convert something TO whatever is here.
}
```

I have a page which looks like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.ConverterPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="using:MyApp.Models"
    xmlns:my="using:MyApp.Controls"
    xmlns:prismMvvm="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
    prismMvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <my:SelectorPage Name="SourceSelector" Grid.Column="0" />
        <my:SelectorPage Name="TargetSelector" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

...where SelectorPage is a user control (I've called it a 'Page' to make the Prism AutoWire work but that's not the issue here) containing a list of items (all working fine) which looks like this...

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.Controls.SelectorPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="using:MyApp.Models"
    xmlns:my="using:MyApp.Controls"
    xmlns:prismMvvm="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
    prismMvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ListView
        Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyList, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.Header>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,8,0,8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic" Text="Header Text" />
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyListItem">
                <my:MyListItemTemplate />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</UserControl>
```

..with code behind as...

```
public sealed partial class SelectorPage : UserControl
{
    private SelectorViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as SelectorViewModel;

    public SelectorPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

SelectorViewModel looks like this...

```
public class SelectorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ConversionSide _side;

    public ConversionSide Side
    {
        get { return _side; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _side, value); }
    }

    // Many lines have been omitted for 'clarity'.
}
```

I would like to be able to set the Side property of SelectorViewModel in XAML like this...

```
<my:SelectorPage Name="SourceSelector" Grid.Column="0" Side="Source" />
<my:SelectorPage Name="TargetSelector" Grid.Column="1" Side="Target" />
```

(Once Side has been set, I do not expect it to ever change.)

How can I do this?

I've looked at using a dependency property but I can't get it to change the property in SelectorViewModel. When I add one in SelectorPage it's visible in the XAML and I can set it but it doesn't actually do anything so I'm probably not using it right. Putting a dependency property in the view model doesn't sound right to me but I could be wrong.
I've had a look around the web - Microsoft documentation, blogs, articles, stack overflow, etc. - but I can't find anything that explains things well enough for me to figure out what I'm supposed to do. The writings I've found seem to be exclusively about getting information from a bound property - which I'm okay with - but what I'm after is **setting** a property from the XAML.

Can anyone give my any clues please? I don't know if I'm just a tiny step away from getting what I want or if I'm miles away.

Comment: You are using the SelectorPage user control on another view. That view should also have a view model and that should have 2 properties like SourceSelector and TargetSelectoor of type SelectorViewModel. Just set the DataContext of each SelectorPage to one of the properties

Comment: I added the extra properties - do they need to be dependency properties? - in the ConverterViewModel (for ConverterPage) - public ConverterPage() { InitializeComponent(); ViewModel.SourceSelectorViewModel = SourceMeasureSelector.ViewModel; ViewModel.TargetSelectorViewModel = TargetMeasureSelector.ViewModel; } - but I can't figure out how to set the Side property for each via the ConverterPage XAML; the Side property does not seem to be available. Is there more I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

This would set the `Side` property of the `SelectorPage` control to `Source`:

A view sets the property of a view model by two-way bind to it. For example, the following `TextBox` sets the `string` property of a view model called `Test` when you change the text in the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

So setting the property of a view model from the view typically applies to controls that handles some kind of input. Any default value of a source property should be defined in the view model:

```
private ConversionSide _side = ConversionSide.Source;
```

You shouldn't define the default values in the view.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance in this area but I don't understand how that answers my question. The Side property of the SelectorPage must be set by ConverterPage - or something at that level - as neither the SelectorPage or SelectorModelView knows whether it will be the Source or Target. It's only after they have both been created when something has to tell each one which it is. Also, there's nothing to bind to the Side property as it's not used in a control; it's only used within the view-model so it knows which one it is - source or target - so it can subscribe/publish the correct messages.

Comment: "Set by the ConverterPage"? How is this MVVM? Pages are views. They shouldn't contain any application logic.

Comment: The SelectorPage can set a property of the ConverterPage but not a property of a view model.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to both UWP and MVVM (including Prism) and am trying to pick things up as I go but it's difficult to learn both from scratch by myself. I know I should try and stay away from putting stuff in the View (code behind) - and have done so up to this point - but I don't know how else to do it. Basically I have two view-models that are created via some static XAML and one needs to be told it is the Source and the other the Target. How would you suggest that I do it?

Comment: What is the "source" of a view model?

Comment: I don't mean the 'source of the view-model'. I'll try and re-word in this limited space. A SelectorPage contains a list of measures that the user can choose from. I need two SelectorPages, left-hand for Source of a conversion (e.g. miles), right-hand for conversion Target (e.g. kilometres). The ConverterPage XAML creates both the SelectorPages but I need to be able to tell one it is the Source (left-hand) and the other the Target (right-hand) so I know which way round to do the conversion. Does that make things a little clearer?

Comment: That should just be a matter of setting the property of the left one to "Source" and the other one to "Target", shouldn't it?

Comment: That's basically my question: How do I tell each view-model whether it's the Source or Target one and where should I do it? Each SelectorPage is a separate item and they don't communicate with each other in any way. ConverterPage contains both the SelectorPages but it only communicates with them via the EventAggregator. So, how do I send a message (or whatever) to tell each SelectorViewModel what it is - Source or Target - when the view-model for ConverterPage has no idea that either exists? What mechanism should I use to say "You're the Source and You're the Target" and where should I use it?

Comment: Where do you instantiate the view model? Can't you just set a property on it when you do this?

Comment: Currently both ConverterPage and SelectorPage use the XAML - prismMvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" - to instantiate the view-model automatically (which is why SelectorPage is not called SelectorUserControl as I originally wanted it). Under the rules of Prism I don't know how else I would do it but I'm willing to learn (especially if I can rename the user controls to something other than pages, which is confusing).

Comment: Don't auto wire the view model. Create it explicitly, either in the XAML or in the code-behind of the view. Then you can easily set a property of it.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm going to have to look at how I should best do that, which might take me some time. Thanks for your help. I'll report back when I've done it (or not). Just a quick follow-up question regarding this: As a general good practice, would you suggest that I not auto-wire all of my view-models or should I use auto-wire unless it gets in the way of what I want to do (like this)? I'm not really comfortable auto-wiring as I don't really know what it's doing in the background. I prefer to do things myself but am glad of the help it gives sometimes.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to auto-wire when you don't need to some custom initialization suff that cannot be done by performed by the container.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. I'll try non-auto-wiring my user controls and see how I get on. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: After some experimentation/hair-pulling I did not figure out how to pass parameters into the view-model instantiation  - I'll need to look into that more at some point - but I think I've come up with a way to do what I currently want via interfaces, inheritance, Container.RegisterType<VM, VM> and ViewModelLocationProvider.Register(V, VM). And I can keep the auto-wiring too. Fingers crossed anyway.